# Filter a List with Java8 only when other List has elements

Tags: java, list, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to write code to filter elements from a *list* if they exist in the another *list*.

The business logic requires me to return all elements from the **first list** if the **second list** is empty.

```
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("a","b","c","d");         
//List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("a","d");       
List<String> list2 = Collections.emptyList();        

if (!list2.isEmpty()) {
  List<String> finalList = list1.stream()
      .map(x -> x)
      .filter(x -> list2.isEmpty() && list2.contains(x))
      .collect(toList());
  return finalList;
} else {
  return list1;
}
```

Is there a better way to do it? Preferably, in a single lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, condition `list2.isEmpty() && list2.contains(x)` is incorrect, and it'll never get evaluated to `true`. Because `list2` can either be empty or contain a particular object, but not both.

Operation `filter()` will *retain* only those elements that match the predicate, hence your stream will always generate an ***empty list***.

Since the possibility of *list2* being empty is eliminated by preceding `if` statement, I assume that the correct filtering condition has to be `list2.contains(x)`.

> Is there a better way to do it? Preferably **in a single lambda** function.

You can achieve that with Java 8 method [`Collection.removeIf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf(java.util.function.Predicate)) that expects a `Predicate` and will *remove* every element from the source that matches the given predicate.

You don't need initial values in the `list1` you can invoke `removeIf()` directly on it, otherwise you need to make a defensive copy.

For better performance, you need to wrap the second list with a `Set`, in this case `contains()` check will be done in a constant time.

```
Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<>(list2);
list1.removeIf(x -> !set2.contains(x); // element will get removed if not present in the set
return list1;
```

Or you can generate a new list like that:

```
Set<String> set2 = new HashSet<>(list2);
return list1.stream()
        .filter(set2::contains)        // element will be preserved if it's present in the set
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // or `toList()` with Java 16+
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try streaming the second list into a set to avoid traversing the entire list each time (O(n^2)) in your filter predicate.

```
public List<String> filterElementsPresentInBothLists(List<String> list1, List<String> list2) {
        assert list2 != null;
        return list2.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toSet(),
                        setView -> setView.isEmpty() ? list1 :
                                list1.stream().filter(setView::contains)
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList())));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the mapping also is not required, and the below one satisfies your requirement,

```
        List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("a","b","c","d");
        //List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList("a","d");
        List<String> list2 = Collections.emptyList();
        List<String> finalList = list1.stream()
                                    .filter(list2::contains)
                                    .toList(); // Java 16+
        List<String> list = toList.isEmpty() ? list2 : finalList;

        System.out.println(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting second list to HashMap can reduce the lookup to O(1) time complexity and hence overall time complexity will be list1.size() + list2.size().

```
        Map<String, String> map = list2.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), Function.identity()));

        list1.stream()
                .filter( x -> list2.isEmpty() || map.containsKey(x))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```